# Is cocoapods-keys is not support to macOS Ventura

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoapods, keychain, cocoapods-app

I tried to run pod install, but it gives me the following error
Cocoapods keys using deprecated syntax

```
warning: 'SecKeychainOpen' is deprecated: first deprecated in macOS 12.0 - Custom keychain management is no longer supported [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
```

Comment: Any new informations? I see the same log in console.